# Error: package 'JavaGD' is not installed for 'arch=x64'

Tags: r

I am running R-2.11.1-x64, on a Win7 machine, with all packages updated through the update command.
I am trying to install the Deducer package. For that I ran:

```
install.packages("Deducer",,"http://rforge.net/")
install.packages('iplots',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
install.packages('JavaGD',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
install.packages('rJava',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
install.packages('iWidgets',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
install.packages('JGR',,'http://www.rforge.net/')
```

Now, when I type

```
> library(Deducer)
```

I get the error:

```
Error: package 'JavaGD' is not installed for 'arch=x64'
```

How to solve this? I tried to solve it by getting the x64-version of JavaGD from the rforge website and installing it manually. This yields

```
> package 'JavaGD' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

but doesn'solve the error message when I try to start up Deducer.

What can solve this?

Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 1):

I just received the following workaround offline, I wanted to share it with anyone having the same issue. As it turns out, there is an issue with JavaGD under R-2.11.1-x64. But there is a working build already for R-2.12. This can be found at 
http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.12/
When I installed that version, the error disappeared, although there is a message saying:

Warning message:
package 'JavaGD' was built under R version 2.12.0

Well, I can live with that!

Thanks, Peter